# Gridview Edit Delete and Update in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

I tried Implementing the code for Edit and Update button for gridview but it doesn't seems working for me. Add button working well but delete and update do not working. During runtime error the error is "An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Unknown column 'p001' in 'where clause'"

Note: type of P_Id in the database is varchar(10), name varch(100), level varchar, value varchar

public partial class ManagePractice : System.Web.UI.Page
{

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindData();
    }
}
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtID = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtID");
    TextBox txtSubject = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtSubject");
    RadioButtonList Level = (RadioButtonList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("RadioButtonList2");
    RadioButtonList PType = (RadioButtonList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
    AddPractice(txtID.Text.Trim(), txtSubject.Text.Trim(), Level.Text.Trim(), PType.Text.Trim());
    BindData();
}
private void AddPractice(string P_Id, string subject, string level, string type)
{
    string connStr = @"Data Source=localhost;Database=ahsschema;User Id=webuser;Password=webuser2014";

    using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        string query = "insert into practice(P_Id,name,level,value) values ('" + P_Id + "','" + subject + "','" + level + "','" + type + "')";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();

    }
}
private void BindData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   string connStr = @"Data Source=localhost;Database=ahsschema;User Id=webuser;Password=webuser2014";
    using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter("select P_Id,level,name,value from practice", cn);
        adp.Fill(dt);

    }
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    BindData();
}

protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    string id = (GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString ());
    DeletePractice(id);
    BindData();


}

protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindData();
}

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
  //  int id = int.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    TextBox txtID = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtID");
    TextBox txtSubject = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtSubject");
   // TextBox Level1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtlevel");
   // TextBox PType1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtPType1");
     RadioButtonList Level = (RadioButtonList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("RadioButtonList2");
     RadioButtonList PType = (RadioButtonList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("RadioButtonList1");

    UpdatePractice( txtID.Text , txtSubject.Text, Level.Text, PType.Text);
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    BindData();

}
private void UpdatePractice( string P_Id, string name, string level, string value)
{
     string connStr = @"Data Source=localhost;Database=ahsschema;User Id=webuser;Password=webuser2014";
    using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        string query = "UPDATE practice SET P_Id='" + P_Id + "',name='" + name + "',level='" + level + "',value='" + value + " WHERE P_Id=" + P_Id + "";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
    }
}
private void DeletePractice(string id)
{
   string connStr = @"Data Source=localhost;Database=ahsschema;User Id=webuser;Password=webuser2014";
    using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        string query = "DELETE FROM practice WHERE P_Id=" + id + "";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First sight:

Since P_Id column has `VARCHAR(10)` datatype, I figured out you forget to include some additional apostrophes on UPDATE & DELETE clause. The correct form of SQL statements should be this (notice additional apostrophe signs around P_Id column):

```
string query = "UPDATE practice SET P_Id='" + P_Id + "',name='" + name + "',level='" + level + "',value='" + value + "' WHERE P_Id= '" + P_Id + "'";
```

and

```
string query = "DELETE FROM practice WHERE P_Id='" + id + "'";
```

Only string values require apostrophes around them, numbers do not.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, the delete button now is working well. But when i click on edit button, it does not enable me to edit any thing. it does not create text boxes to editing.

Comment: Make sure GridView1_RowEditing and GridView1_RowUpdating events fire properly when edit button event triggered on debugging. If your aspx file contains some Javascript errors please show them to narrow down your grid editing problem.

Comment: I show the tutorial that i got the code from it, when he clicked on Edit button, other content in this row convert from label to text box, but my code does not convert it when i clicked on Edit button. I don't know how can solve it. shall i create new textboxes in Item Template for editing?

Comment: Probably you can try `asp:TemplateField` after `Columns` element with `EditItemTemplate` that contains required `TextBox` with binding parameter to column name, e.g. `Text = '<%# Bind("Subject") %>'`. Grid's edit button can take place on CommandField: `<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />`